# Can I use data from 2 different httpclients in one function

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have 2 arrays being populated by 2 different HTTPClients. I want to be able to pull data from both of these arrays in my function. I tried using a callback and it works great for one, but when I tried to add the other httpclient and add another callback, it will not work. Can I even use multiple callbacks like this? Here is my code:

```
var myGeocodeArray = [];
var myUserArray = [];

function retrieveData(myCallback, myCallBack2) {
    // Load geocode data
    xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=MyAdress');

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myCallback(myData);
    };
    xhr.send();

    // Load user data
    loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    loader.open("GET", "http://example.com/getGroups.php");

    loader.onload = function() {
        var myUserData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myCallBack2(myUserData);
    };
    loader.send();
};


retrieveData(function(returnVar, returnVar2) {
    myGeocodeArray = returnVar;
    myUserArray = returnVar2;
    populateMap();
});


function populateMap() {
    Ti.API.info(myGeocodeArray);
    Ti.API.info(myUserArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPClient are by default working asynchronously, so your code should work properly as it is. You can log how request state is changing with simple callback:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
  console.log(this.readyState); // values from 0 to 4
  // For more descriptive readyState, small snippet using underscore.js:
  // Strings: UNSENT, HEADERS_RECIEVED, LOADING, DONE
  console.log( _.keys(this)[_.values(this).lastIndexOf(this.readyState)] );
}
```

If you want to make http calls synchronously you have to in open() method provide third parameter set to false:

```
loader.open("GET", "http://example.com/getGroups.php", false);
```

For more information check [Appcelerator documentation about HTTPClient object](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient).

**UPDATE:** The problem with your code is in function retrieveData() which accepts **two** parameters: myCallback and myCallBack2 but when you are calling this function you just pass one parameter:

```
retrieveData(function(returnVar, returnVar2) {
    myGeocodeArray = returnVar;
    myUserArray = returnVar2;
    populateMap();
});
```

For more readability, check this refactored code:

```
var myCallback = function(returnVar, returnVar2) {
    myGeocodeArray = returnVar;
    myUserArray = returnVar2;
    populateMap();
}

retrieveData(myCallback);
```

So myCallBack2 is undefined and cause the error.

You can fixing by removing myCallBack2 from your code and just use one parameter for callback function:

```
function retrieveData(myCallback) {
    // Load geocode data
    xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=MyAdress');

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myCallback(myData);  
    };
    xhr.send();

    // Load user data
    loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    loader.open("GET", "http://example.com/getGroups.php");

    loader.onload = function() {
        var myUserData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myCallback(myUserData);
    };
    loader.send();
};
```

This code from this point can be still cleaned up a lot but I try to keep it as simple as possible, so it's easier to see where is significant change.

Comment: It is not letting my second callback work. It is giving me an error: 'undefined' is not a function evaluating 'myCallBack2(myUserData)'. I know the data is good because when I run them separate, they are both returning data fine; it is just when I try to combine them is when the error comes. It is like it will not run more than one creatHTTPClient

Comment: Check if you defined **myCallBack2** function. Remember it's case sensitive name. I suspect you created **myCallback2()** function and misspelled it.

Comment: Well, I thought I defined it under my second onload function - myCallBack2(myUserData); Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Ok, now I saw your mistake. Check my updated answer.